# Reaching to a directory in git

Tags: git, directory

I have created a directory named **Temporary_add_to_version_control** on **Desktop**. Now I am trying to reach to that directory by typing cd ~/Desktop/Temporary_add_to_version_control/ in git. I am getting the error message:-
*bash: cd: /c/Users/preet/Desktop/Temporary_add_to_version_control/: No such file or directory.*
Can someone tell me what this error message means and how do I get to my directory?

Comment: Is this perhaps related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository ?

Comment: ~ expands to home directory, making it the absolute path as displayed in error message.
Try giving complete proper path or relative path from your present working directory (pwd) in terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is telling that in your desktop that directory doesn't exist.

if the directory showing in your desktop just right click on the directory in that options you will able to see git bash here .

click on git bash here.